Is epoch necessary while using A2C algorithm?
I don't know if this was answered before or not, bear with me please.
For an energy grid control problem, I am using the advantage actor-critic (A2C) algorithm for decision making.
I implemented it as follows:
For each RL episode:
score and memory are cleared/re-initialized
interaction with the environment (a simulation of the energy grid for a given period) -> collecting memory=(S, A, R, S')
either at the end of the episode (or if simulation's iteration is % to a rolling_length period) I call a "train" method where i do the training of the A&C NNs
So here is my question, in the "train" method, for a number of epochs, I perform a forward pass for both the Actor and Critic using the states S collected, I use the previously stored log_prob calculated using Actor's predictions during the simulation to calculate its loss, while for the advantage function I use the discounted future rewards which are calculated with the R stored.
The first question is, since I am doing an on-policy learning, should I do call "train" just once or a loop with a number of epochs is the correct way?
My second question is, should I still perform a forward pass during the "train" method, even if I technically have done that during the simulation where my Actor predicts (mu, sigma) from which I sample my actions?

You should generally call "train" once per batch of data in on-policy methods like A2C, without multiple epochs.
A forward pass during training is necessary to compute accurate gradients for both the Actor and Critic.

Thank you for your answer.
If I understand correctly, I still need to do a forward pass even if I memorize the log_probs beforehands.
As for epochs, since it is on-policy, I only update the networks using the exploration data once ? I can't have multiple epochs ?
Since you talk about batch, even on-policy methods can use them ?
Thank you !

You still need to do a forward pass to compute log_probs based on the current policy.
In many on-policy algorithms, multiple epochs are used, as long as the updates don't change the policy too drastically.
On-policy methods can indeed use mini-batches for training to make learning more efficient
